# Set Push Notification in android

Tags: android

I have an Api.  Suppose this api http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/  has this contact which I'm displaying in list view. I want  to set a push notification in our application, such that when ever a new contact is added in the api  then  there should be a notification in our application that a new contact has been uploaded. This Notification should be displayed even if the application is not open or launched.

For example: It should function like "Time of INDIA" android app. When news updates come then it shows a Notification.
 I am new in android. Please help me. hHw i will do this? Please send me example sources or  post me related blog or tell me logic. How i will do this i have server access also.

Thanx

Comment: Possible duplicate of the OP's earlier posts: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12560954/450534 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12559323/450534

Comment: yes because i dint get solution of this problme

Comment: You don't create duplicate questions for that reason. Read through this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: please help me to solve this Problem ..

Answer (score 4):

You can use GCM for this,

Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that helps developers send data from servers to their Android applications on Android devices. This could be a lightweight message telling the Android application that there is new data to be fetched from the server (for instance, a movie uploaded by a friend), or it could be a message containing up to 4kb of payload data (so apps like instant messaging can consume the message directly). The GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery to the target Android application running on the target device

This document describes how to write an Android application and the server-side logic, using the helper libraries (client and server) provided by GCM.

Check these links,

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html

http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/19226-android-push-notification-gcm-framework-tutorial.html

http://fundroiding.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/google-cloud-messaging-for-android-gcm-simple-tutorial/

for client side app you can find the code here

https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova

Comment: ok i m trying to do this but please send me You email id if some thing will not implemnetd then i ll post Project coz i have dead line today ..about this project help me